# Movieclip: Attatching/Removing a Movieclip VS Hiding and Showing a Moveclip

Tags: actionscript, hide, show

I have this tool tip that is created every so often. What is the appropriate actionscript etiquite?

A. To Create and remove the tooltip moveclip when needed?

or

B. To hide and show the tooltip movieclip when needed?

Answer (score 0):

With these A and B, the answer is B, because creating and then removing an object a lot of times creates a lot of garbage in the memory, which eventually leads to garbage collector calls, that slow your SWF's performance. You can easily go with a single tooltip MC, just fill it with information that corresponds to the new mouse coordinates before you show it.

There is another question, not so straightforward as yours, about how to hide and show a movie clip, either via `visible` property or via `addChild()` and `removeChild()` (AS3 only). If you are using AS2 or AS1, use `visible` property to hide and show your tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to hide something in Actionscript : Alpha, visible and remove child.

**Apha:**  If you turn the alpha zero the renderer always comes to this displayObject and renders it at alpha zero. So the object is always rendered you just cannot see it.

**Visible == false** In this case the object still exists in your displaylist. So the renderer comes to the object. Sees it's property is false and leaves it but it still exists in the display list.

**removeChild** This means that you're removing the object from the display list. This means that the renderer never had to even check for it. Which makes it the fastest option.

addChild doesn't take that much computing power as visible check. I'm sure you can find benchmarks on this.

If you don't have a lot of objects on yours screen and the tooltip is there every second I'd go with visible is false. In all other cases go with the third option.

On a side note, I've found it always easier to manage them with a toolTipManager. A class that makes sure that you have one tooltip on the screen because usually users only use one tooltip. So that makes things easier for me. I just always create the necessary tooltips and add them to the displaylist when required and remove them. (Not recreate them) At the same time have only one tooltip on stage.